# vue input radio not checked with v-model

Tags: vue.js, radio-button, checked

When I use `:checked`, it works. But if I add `v-model`, it does not work.

```html
<div v-for="answer in the_data[current].answers" id="answers">
    <p>
        <input
            type="radio"
            name="answer"
            :id="answer"
            :value="answer"
            v-model="the_answer"
            v-bind:checked="answer == 'girl'"
        >  
        @{{ answer }}
    </p>
</div>
```

I need to use `v-model`

Answer (score 9):

I believe the reason is the `input` checked is binded to `the_answer` and somehow the initial value of `the_answer` is not one of the picked values, and this binding overwrites the `checked` attribute, since whatever is checked should be the value the input is binded to, i.e. `the_answer`. Specifying the initial value of `the_answer` should give you the same behavior of checked:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    the_answer: 'girl'               // initialize the_answer to be your checked option
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <div v-for="answer in ['boy', 'girl']">
    <p>
      <input 
        type="radio" 
        name="answer" 
        :id="answer"
        :value="answer"
        v-model="the_answer">
      @{{ answer }}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```